# How to download easygui for python3.3?

Tags: 13.10, python, python-2.7, python3

I have python 2.7 and python 3.3 in my Ubuntu 13.10 system.I have easygui in-built for python2.7 but not for python3.3.But when I download the zip file of easygui and unzip it and type "python3 setup.py install".It tells me permission denied why is this so.And how do i know how many python versions do I have in my system?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "permission denied" message, maybe make sure that

1. `setup.py` is executable. You might do a simple `chmod +x setup.py`.
2. You run the install command with a sufficient privilege level. You may try `sudo python3 setup.py install`.

To know what are the different `python` versions installed on your machine, I would run

```
 ll /usr/bin | grep python
```

You should end up with a couple of directories and symlinks of the different python versions. Typically, you may have `python` pointing to your `python2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Try from a terminal:

> sudo apt-get install python3-easygui

Or install synaptic package manager:

> sudo apt-get install synaptic

Then install it from there.